# If $p$th, $q$th, $r$th and $s$th terms of an A.P are in G.P. Then show $p-q$, $q-r$, $r-2$ are also in G.P.

Tags: arithmetic-progressions, geometric-progressions

> If $p$th, $r$th and $s$th terms of an arithmetic progression are in a geometric progression, then show that $(p-q), (q-r)$ and $(r-2)$ are also in a geometric progression.

I want to understand the middle steps of the question please help

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: When yopu say $(p-q)$, do you mean $(p-q)^{\text{th}}$?

Comment: There is a mismatch between the title and the problem. What exactly are the terms? Is it $p, r, s$ or $p, q, r$?